# Programming Library or Software to Allow User to View and Fill out Pdfs within a Windows 10 App

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer, windows-10

I'm trying to design a Windows 10 Universal application where one of the features is that it downloads pdfs from various websites. I would like to be able to open and view these pdfs natively in the application while retaining the functionality to fill them out (obviously only for pdfs that normally have such functionality). It is my understanding that Microsoft has no support for this as their pdf class simply converts the pdf to a bitmap then displays it as a .png file. Does anyone have any software recommendations for a programming library or a plugin that my app can call that they have found success with? (free or paid, obviously free is preferable)

Requirements:

- Can Open Pdfs within the application, without opening a new window
- Pdfs maintain functionality in terms of filling out forms

Bonus:

- Zooming in on pdfs

I would also be interested in suggestions for software that is soon to be released (being as Windows 10 itself was just released)